# Assigning jobs to BackgroundWorker thread one at a time

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, backgroundworker

My silverlight application fetches *file sets* from a webservice (async). The webservice method accepts an array of file names and returns the set of files (also as an array). The silverlight client makes several such requests for *file sets*.

The client issues many requests to the webservice at once. I need **a** `BackgroundWorker` thread at the client to process received *file sets* **one after the other**.

How can I collect all the *file sets* as and when they receive and give these sets to the `BackgroundWorker` thread one at a time.

EDIT:
I could not run multiple BackgorundWorkers as the file set processing module is not thread-safe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387640/synchronous-work-in-a-backgroundworker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) / [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) to hold the information about file sets to be processed... in the backgroundworker you just have `while` loop dequeuing the next file set and processing it... the mentioned collections are threadsafe and really fast since most operations are implemented lock-free...

Comment: There could be a scenario where concurrent queue is empty and the waiting to be filled. Will there be a problem when the worker tries to dequeue it?

Comment: there won't be problem - either it comes back with false on `TryDequeue` (`ConcurrentQueue`) / `TryTake` (`BlockingCollection`) OR it sleeps till something is filled `Take` (`BlockingCollection`) - please follow the links...

Comment: @codr3: Neither of these options are available in Silverlight (unless you write them yourself)

Comment: Found a Silverlight ported concurrent queue that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The `backgroundworker` has no built-in Listen mechanism. It is supposed to perform a long action and terminate.

One solution could consist in firing up one `backgroundworker` for each file set.

If the processing of those file sets must be synchronized, you could decide to push each request into a queue (basically an `array`. Make sure you synchronize access to it). Whenever you `backgroundworker` is done processing a file set, it would report to the main thread (`ProgressChanged` event IIRC) and loop over further possible requests in the array. Whenever the array is empty, the worker exits.

Pay attention though: If the worker exits while you are sending a request, you'll have a problem. That's why a basic thread may prove stronger than a background thread, especially if you can't know whether there will be further file sets to process. It all depends on your workflow.

Comment: I could not run multiple BackgorundWorkers as the file set processing module is not thread-safe.